# Spring Batch Job reader is running continuously although the scheduled time is 5 minutes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, batch-file, spring-batch

I have configured a Spring Batch job with

```
        triggerBean.setCronExpression(task.getCronExpression());
        triggerBean.setStartTime(task.getStartTime());
        LOG.info("Scheduling task {} to {}", task.getTaskName(), task.getCronExpression());
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobBean, triggerBean);
```

Now I have a reader which reads about let say 100 of db rows and then extract the list and give it to writer, now my writer used to process some of the list entries let say 50 of the list provided by reader. The job scheduled for after 10 minutes but I am observing that reader is running continuously infinitely.

Another example: 
Let say my Reader reads 1 db rows with status `column = 1 and count = 4` and give it the writer and I have implemented writer to delete rows entries with `column = 1 and count =5`. For this scenario my reader is running continuously and bringing that same data again and again for the writer but the writer cannot process it so this causes infinite loop for the reader.
Please suggest what is the problem here and what may be the solution.

Note: Another ticket is raised but i am not sure what may be the issue.
Have a look at it.

[Spring Batch Job Running in Infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834725/spring-batch-job-running-in-infinite-loop)

Comment: Please provide your cron expression for the scheduler & the reader code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return null in the reader once you completes the reading of all records from the DB if you are using your own reader.Please check your custom reader.